# Column shifted down in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I opened the document today and found it this way!
how can I move the whole right column one row up, so that all rows are aligned again
[Visual of the document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3R57.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a new value was added for this column at the first row, you could delete it
and shift the other values one row up this way:

- Click inside this column at the first character of the second row
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click inside this column at the end of the last value
  in the last row. This will select all the values in the column except the first.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy these values
- Select the entire column
- Press <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete all the values in the column
- Click inside the column in the first row
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to insert the copied values in the
  following rows.

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked